# How to fix Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: javascript, html

I never had this error before: how to solve? It refers to the following file:

> /METest/js/function.php?title=Home&sidebar=1:6

This is the content of the file:

```
document.title = "Home";
document.querySelector(".sidebar").style.display = "block";
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: that means `querySelector()` returned `null`

Comment: try `querySelectorAll()` instead because you are selectign based on class name

Comment: @Mi-Creativity The script didn't work after I changed it to `querySelectorAll()` and gave me 3 more errors.

Comment: it does work https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/3bm5Lej9/

Comment: Aside: Why is there a php file in your js folder?

Comment: @Mi-Creativity It gives me the following: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined(anonymous function) @ function.php?title=Home&sidebar=1:6

Comment: @cricket_007 The file is actually a JS file with php in it, it's because I can't use php in ajax scripts.

Comment: if there's only one element with this class name, try this `document.getElementsByClassName("sidebar")[0].style.display = "block";`

Comment: @Mi-Creativity That gives me the following: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined(anonymous function) @ function.php?title=Home&sidebar=1:4
VM3257:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined

Comment: These errors are not in this line, double check that you have that DOM element, maybe it is an `id=` not `class=`, try `console.log()` also put your javascript at the bottom of the page at the bottom of the page , post your HTML code of that part here within the question

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that snippet isn't running until the DOM is loaded. This `document.querySelector(".sidebar")` will be null if that's running too soon.